# shell script cron job not working

Tags: cron, freebsd

I'm on FreeBSD11. I have a shell script code as cron job that check the zfs pool status and save it in a sqlite database.
when I run it from terminal, it work properly but in crontab it does't work.
The crontab:

```
 #
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/etc:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/etc/myjob/pool
#
#minute hour    mday    month   wday    who     command
#

*/1    *     *    *   *   root  /usr/local/etc/myjob/pool/pool.sh
```

my script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
pool=$(/sbin/zpool status | grep pool |awk '{print $2}')
for i in $pool
do
    status=$(/sbin/zpool status ${i} |grep state|awk '{print $2}')


    echo 'update mytbl set status =  '\'''$status''\'';'|sqlite3  /usr/local/var/db/myproject/myDataBase.db

done
```

Can you help me figure out the mistake?

Comment: Redirect the output to a file and see what error messages it might be giving you. (Append `>/tmp/cronpool.log 2>&1`, for example.)

Comment: Please confirm how you added this to a `crontab`, and if you did it by editing a file please provide its name and location.

Comment: Does your script depend on the current directory it's run in? That's a common gotcha with cronjobs. Can you post your script in your question, it's likely that the problem lies in it.

Is it possible that your script take more than 1 minute to run? Maybe the problem is that the script runs concurrently with itself.

Apart from that, note that */1 is redundant and that you can write *.

Comment: Do you use environment variable, which might not be defined?

Comment: I added the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the full path of `sqlite` in your script.